# Problem with views edit link not appearing

Tags: views, 6, users, panels

I have created a view (block) that has contained in its fields user account information (including content profile fields). Along with that, there is an edit link to edit the profile information. The problem I am experiencing is; when logged in as a regular user, the edit link does not appear. When logged in as user 1 it does appear. I thought this would be a permission issue but I can't see what should be checked. I think I have enabled all the necessary permissions. Aren't users enabled to edit their profiles by default?

Here is a screenshot of the view's settings:

[image: screenshot]

I am using Drupal 6.26 and views 6.2.16 and displaying this view in a panel. Any suggestions as to what I may be missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem. I had missed enabling access user profiles permission for authenticated users.